# Foreach wait for task to complete

Tags: c#, foreach, task-parallel-library

I have a such situtation:

```
        foreach (var item in listBoxFileNames.SelectedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am not waiting");
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSourcve = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = tokenSourcve.Token;

            Task task1 = new Task(() =>
                {
                    ProcessDatas(); // method
                }
                , token);

            task1.Start();
        }
```

I want to make foreach to wait task's completion. BUt it is not waiting. It showing me MessageBox immediately after each messagBox.

Comment: Why do you create a task if you will block waiting for each task?

Comment: User will choose some files and will select all files which he wants to process. foreach will get all selected items. But it must wait for the previous task to finish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're *starting* the task, which will then execute in the background. If you want the loop to behave entirely synchronously, just call `ProcessDatas()` not in a task at all. You *could* start it and then wait for it to finish - but it's not clear what benefit that would give you.

If you want to *start* all the tasks in parallel, but then wait for them afterwards, you could create a `List<Task>` and then call [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235659.aspx) - or just use `Parallel.ForEach` to start with.

Comment: But the window isn't responding me.

Comment: @FerhadJabiyev: It's not clear what your comment means, nor which thread your code is running in, nor what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you please show me what i must change in my code? Why Task.Wait() isnt working in my code, if i ad it after task1.start(). Foreach isnt waiting...

Comment: @FerhadJabiyev: You're still not being at all clear about what you're trying to do - and saying that something "isn't working" without any more detail doesn't help either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing.But now i want to ask a question in a forum. But i cant do it. Site is keping to tell me to change smth in that question. And i didn;t know what to change? Also to tell the truth i dont remember what was the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make a Bool that becomes true once the task is done then put the rest in a if (bool) loop?

Comment: Are you saying that he should do something like `while (!finished) { /* do nothing */ }`? That's a terrible idea, because it wastes CPU doing no useless work.

Comment: @svick Okay, I just wrote the first possible solution that I could think of. It was just an idea not a finished answere. Maybe it would have fit better as a comment :P (new here)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can just call the [Task.Wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
task1.Wait();
```

and read this [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)